# Drupal - use content type field in Pathauto

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a Drupal 6 web site and would like to use a node field as part of the URL (in the [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) settings). The field name is "*place*" and the content type is "*events*". I tried combinations such as `[node:place]`, and `[events:place]` in the Node paths section of the Pathauto module, but the tokens don't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example tokens you've given are for Drupal 7, not Drupal 6. In Drupal 6 to get a particular CCK field you'll want a token like this:

```
[field_name_of_field-raw]
```

Just go to `admin/build/path/pathauto` and have a look in the 'Replacement Patterns' list...under CCK Text/CCK File/CCK Number etc. you'll find the token value for the specific field you're using.

Comment: Worked like a charm!, Thanks so much Clive!